# How do schema validation functions work in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

While working through a MEAN stack tutorial, I find myself puzzled by the following mongoose verification code.

**user-service.js**

```
exports.findUser = function(email, next){
    User.findOne({email:email.toLowerCase()}, function(err,user){
        next(err, user);
    })
};
```

**user.js**

```
var userService = require('../services/user-service');

var userSchema = new Schema({  
    ...
    email:      {type: String, required: 'Please enter your email'},
    ...
});

userSchema.path('email')
    .validate(function(value,next){
        userService.findUser(value, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return next(false);
            }
            next(!user);
        });
    }, 'That email is already in use');
```

1. Every time the `userSchema` is accessed in any way, `userSchema.path('email').validate` **also** fires and validates the email String. This validation could also have been done up in the `userSchema` object, except it would have been very messy.
2. in `.validate(function(value, next)...`, `value` is the email string, and `next` is given nothing and is undefined. (right?)
3. If so, then I don't see how `return next(false)` or `next(!user)` can work.
4. I'm familiar with `next` in  other situations, but what is `next` doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it works:

```
userSchema.path('email').validate(function (email, next) {
    // look for a user with a given email
    // note how I changed `value` to `email`
    userService.findUser(email, function (err, user) {
        // if there was an error in finding this user
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            // call next and pass along false to indicate an error
            return next(false)
        }
        // otherwise, call next with whether or not there is a user
        // `user === null` -> then `!user === true`
        // `user === { someObject }` -> then `!user === false`
        return next(!user)
    })
    // error message
}, 'That email is already in use')
```

To go along with your points:

1. Yes, this function validates the email path.
2. Yes, `value` is the email, so use better variable naming and call it `email` instead of `value`; `next` is just that: a function that says "continue to the next step."
3. See the comments in the code above. But, tldr: if a user with that email exists, then `!user` is `false`; if the user doesn't exist, `!user` is `true`. If `next` is passed a false-y value, it thinks there's an error. A truth-y value means everything was okay.
4. It calls the "next" step. For example

   ```
   app.get('/admin*', function (req, res, next) {
       req.status = 'I was here!'
       next()
   })

   app.get('/admin/users/view', function (req, res, next) {
       console.log(req.status)    // ==> 'I was here!'
       res.render('admin/users/view.jade', { someLocals })
   })
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes certain things more clear -- but 'next' in my code still seems to be meaningless. Why not return 'false' or '!user' by themselves? Would those simple booleans not be enough of an answer for '.validate'  to do its job?

Comment: and in your example #4... the "next" step is defined as 'any code that is written lower on the page' ? That is the source of my confusion. In my code, there is no predetermined 'next' task to do.

Comment: The "next" step could just be "is everything okay?" If not, the error, `"That email is already in use"` is thrown. Also, you can `return false` because the code is async. If you returned false, it would just return the value to the lambda function `function (err, user) { /* etc */ }`, not the validate function.

Comment: Got it. There may be a typo in your last comment though. 'can' should be 'cannot'. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. I meant to say `cannot`.

Comment: I think the key element I was missing is: 'next' is like the 'success' or 'done' in a jQuery AJAX call. The difference is, you have to provide the 'next' in the arguments, (even though it is generated by node), whereas you don't have to provide 'done' or 'success'. Let me know if this is wrong.

Comment: `next` is an argument passed to the callback by mongoose and it just means "continue with this [the passed] state." In a $.ajax call, `done`/`success` means "after the task is completed, finish with this step." In this case, you're saying, "okay, the current task is done; permission to move along to the next one [if it exists]." A good analogy would be a construction line, where you cinderblocks along. Each worker calls "next," and either passes the construction bag or tells the next guy, "Oh no! This bag is broken." Mongoose is the "next guy" with schema validation and wants true/false.

Comment: And 'next' could be called anything. Even 'done'. Yay. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
userSchema.path('email_id').validate(function(value, done) {    
this.model('User').count({ email_id: value }, function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    } 
    // If `count` is greater than zero, "invalidate"
    done(!count);
});
}, 'Email already exists');
```